# MySQL order by clause with varchar type in the mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query. One data field called 'fileno' with varchar type and the data is in the following way:

```
===================
id   |  fileno
===================
 1   |  16/12
 2   |  15/91
 3   |  15/70
 4   |  16/07
===================
```

Now i need to order the fields in descending order and i am expecting the fields to be ordered in descending order. But not working fine. The expected order form is below:

```
16/12
16/07
15/91
15/70
```

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    fileno
FROM
    customer_request
ORDER BY
    fileno DESC
```

Comment: Please add the query that you tried.

Comment: Your query is correct. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff210/1). What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: @PrerakSola Careful: it only appears correct because all digits have the same width.  If his data included digits of varying width it would not work.  See this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0a06/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I do understand that. But for the data provided by OP in the question, it should be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, fileno
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(fileno, INSTR(fileno, '/') + 1) AS UNSIGNED)    DESC,
         CAST(SUBSTRING(fileno, 1, INSTR(fileno, '/') - 1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Can you pls try fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46da53/1 i just tried the code mentioned by you and iam getting a wrong output. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @SanjuMenon This looks right to me, at least it matches your requirement.  It sorts first by the first digit, then by the second digit.  Do you want some other sort order?

Comment: Yes you can see in the data 15 and 16. That's the short form of year 2015 and 2016. Now what iam looking is first it has to sought 15 or 16 and then the other 2 digits

Comment: so as per the new fiddle the data has to be sorted by 
55/16
53/16
3/16
56/15

Comment: ok. Thank you for your time. Need to find another way. Thank you

Comment: Wait...you want to sort by the second column _first_, then the _first_ column second?  Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes exactly. That's what iam looking at

Comment: Absolutely fine. Its working well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's solution is perfect. Another way would be to replace `/` from the string and sort it in `DESC` order

Here is the sample query:

```
SELECT id, fileno
FROM customer_request
ORDER BY REPLACE(fileno, '/', '') DESC
```

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4f3cf/1)

Comment: Clever idea, but it will lead to problems.  Example: `1/60` would sort the same as `16/0`, assuming the digits could have varying character width.  And if they don't have varying width, then you should not even need to remove the slash in the first place.